# How to write regular expression for found href of a tags?

Tags: html, regex

I need to found href of a tags in string such as this .

```
<li><a href="http://bipardeh94.blogfa.com" target="_blank">باغ بلور</a><span class="ur">bipardeh94.blogfa.com</span><span class="ds">فرهنگی-خبری-علمی</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://avaejam.blogfa.com" target="_blank">هزار نکته </a><span class="ur">avaejam.blogfa.com</span><span class="ds"> يك نكته از هزار نكته  باشد تا بعد </span></li>
    <li><a href="http://prkangavar.blogfa.com" target="_blank">روابط عمومی دانشگاه آزاداسلامی کنگاور</a><span class="ur">prkangavar.blogfa.com</span><span class="ds">اخبار دانشگاه</span></li>
```

I use this code :

```
   string regex = "href=\"(.*)\"";
        Match match = Regex.Match(codeHtml, regex);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            textBox1.Text += match.Value +"\n";
        }
```

This code found first href and then return all codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this regex work?

```
string regex = "href=\"([^\"]*)\"";
```

`[^\"]*` allows everything inside the href's quotes to be anything but a quote

For how to match all tags, please use [Regex.Matches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I use this. This return one href such as (   href="http://akhbarearesht.blogfa.com"
  ) only. I want return all links that  exist inside of href attr such as (  http://akhbarearesht.blogfa.com   )

Comment: @programmer138200, make sure you use `Matches` to find multiple occurences. `Match` only finds the first one.

Comment: I change the Match to matches But get error .How to change my codes to fix this?

Comment: @programmer138200 Please look at the Regex.Matches method documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx. Specifically, the example

Comment: I use this code and solded ( foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))  ) . Joseph Young Thank you very much